# AngularJS doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Would any of you help me understand why these codes don't work? Though I am new to AngularJS, I think I followed all instructions.

Simply I have index.html and app.js as shown below, but when I open index.html, it shows nothing (blank page).

```js
(function(){
 var app = angular.module("store",[]);     
 app.contorller("StoreController", function($scope){
  this.products = gems; 
 });
 
 var gems = [
  {
   name: 'Dodecachedron1',
   price: 1.95,
   description: 'In geometry, a dodecahedron is any polyhedron with twelve flat faces. The most familiar dodecahedron is the regular dodecahedron, which is a Platonic solid',
   canPurchase: true
  },
  {
   name: 'Dodecachedron2',
   price: 2.95,
   description: 'In geometry, a dodecahedron is any polyhedron with twelve flat faces. The most familiar dodecahedron is the regular dodecahedron, which is a Platonic solid',
   canPurchase: false
  }   
 ];
})();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app='store'>
 <head>
  <title>Gem Online Store</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body class="well"" ng-controller='StoreController'>
  <div ng-repeat='product in StoreController.products'>
   <h1>{{product.name}}</h1>
   <em class="pull-right">${{product.price | currency}} </em>
   <p>{{product.description}}</p>
   <button ng-show='product.canPurchase'>Add to cart</button>   
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

- You need to set your scope to the products variable to be used
- Fix double quote in "well""
- Typo in app.controller
- you do not need StoreController as a prefix in your repeat
- Update your css to a cdn
- Remove extra "$" since currency filter adds it already
- This demo I removed "app.js" as a dependency but you will need that in your code

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module("store", []);

  app.controller("StoreController", function($scope) {
    $scope.products = gems;
  });

  var gems = [{
    name: 'Dodecachedron1',
    price: 1.95,
    description: 'In geometry, a dodecahedron is any polyhedron with twelve flat faces. The most familiar dodecahedron is the regular dodecahedron, which is a Platonic solid',
    canPurchase: true
  }, {
    name: 'Dodecachedron2',
    price: 2.95,
    description: 'In geometry, a dodecahedron is any polyhedron with twelve flat faces. The most familiar dodecahedron is the regular dodecahedron, which is a Platonic solid',
    canPurchase: false
  }];
})();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="store">
<head>
  <title>Gem Online Store</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <!--<script src="app.js"></script>-->
</head>
<body class="well">
  <div ng-controller="StoreController">
    <div ng-repeat="product in products">
      <h1>{{product.name}}</h1>
      <em class="pull-right">{{product.price | currency}} </em>
      <p>{{product.description}}</p>
      <button ng-show="product.canPurchase">Add to cart</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure why I have -2 here. NO one has offered feedback why?? I listed the issues and the code supplied works. If you downvote comment why you are downvoting.

Comment: The reason you are getting negative reputation for this is that the problem of the OP is typo. These problems cannot be reproduce and the answer wouldn't help other people. You should use comments to point these out and flag the question instead of answering.